# Developing a roguelike in Python 3.4, looking for help randomly generating levels

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, roguelike

I'm running into some issues cracking exactly how to do this all myself, and I figure this has very likely been done before. Does anyone have any suggestions for addons to use, insightful places to look at, and anything else that might be of service?

Comment: This is way off-topic.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you are looking to do is procedurally generate a dungeon.

There is a lot of information available about doing just that on the [procedural content generation wiki](http://pcg.wikidot.com/pcg-algorithm:dungeon-generation).

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.